# Dell server doesn't accept new memory modules

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a Dell T110 II from the 2 GB RAM that it came with (1 stick - 2GB - Samsung part number M391B5773CH0) to 8 GB using 2 x 4 GB 1333MHz memory modules (Corsair CMV8GX3M2A1333C9). However, I cannot get these new chips to work.

Dell don't seem to have any idea why they don't work, and they have already replaced them multiple times with no luck.

No combination works, only the old single module alone brings the system to work.

I have checked that the combinations and slot choices are in accordance with the Hardware Owners Manual and it all checks out.

Diagnostics LEDs show an error: 1 and 3 are on (see page 18 in the [manual](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t110-2_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf)).

Has anyone seen this problem before? Any idea what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Is the memory you're installing ECC memory?

Answer (score 2):

From page 86 of the [T110 II Manual](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t110-2_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf):

> "Your system supports DDR3 ECC unbuffered memory modules (UDIMMs)."

The Samsung module you mentioned appears to be unbuffered ECC, while the Corsair modules are not.

The solution is to install unbuffered ECC memory, as indicated in the manual.